# Is it posible to emulate bluetooth HID with android phone?

Tags: android, bluetooth, hid

Is it posible to emulate bluetooth HID with android phone?

I`m newb in android, but I want to try code application which make phone looks like bluetooth keyboard on PC.

Comment: Try using BlueputDroid application available in market, though it has limitations...

Comment: @ashish it does not work with my devices. its clear that i need.